# Organizing CMS folders

Tags: cme

Currently the multi-brand Tridion implementation I am working on has following folder structure in each publications

02 Global Publications

Global

Local

Images
03 Brand Publications

Global

Local

Images
08 Country Publications

Global

Local

Images

All files are under Global folder; Local and Images folder are empty.

My related questions are :
1. whether this is a default structure provided by Tridion.
2. If yes, what is the any significance of each folder.
3. If no, is there any recommended structure or its completely requirement driven.
4. What is the impact if requirement arises to change the folder structure once all CT, PTs are developed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope below answers might help you:

- By default if you install the Tridion, then it does not come with any specific folder structure and just with the Building Block folder. However, if you choose to use the TRI (Tridion Reference Implementation), then you will have a default Blueprinting as well as a Folder hierarchy
- As such you can use any folder for anything, however, you can think of managing it from a long vision perspective. Further, if you want to segregate your items like Template and Content apart from the permission perspective then also you can think of putting them in entirely different folder. Many such scenario could be there.
- In my opinion, it is mostly requirement driven, however, you may think of keeping your content in a separate branch of folder and your system items like schema, templates, TBB etc. in a separate branch
- Changing the folder structure with in the scope of a Publication will not have any significant impact except if in your code you are referring them through the WebDav URLs. So basically, if you are changing the folder structure, then you need to update the WebDav URL where ever is required.

Answer (score 3):

### Defaults and Standards

Aside from Building Blocks and Default Template Building Blocks (upon creation) there are no defaults, but you'll find the following as almost a standard:

- Building Blocks
- Content
- System

System will often have folders for Schemas, Templates, and other system-related items as Pankaj suggests.

DXA had a new recommendation to move "System" building blocks into module folders. Either way, you can optionally hide the higher-level System or module folder from most users as long as you give read permissions to Schemas and Embedded Schemas to your editors so they can create Components based on those Schemas.

### Organizing Content

The SDL Education courses describe 3 ways to organize:

- By Department
- By Channel or website (or in your case, local vs. global use)
- By Department or Business unit

There's also by date. These aren't specific to Tridion--look at any file system to see the same patterns. Indeed, I'll often ask customers what their current folder organization looks like (outside Tridion) before finding a good fit for their Tridion setup.

### Optimized Organization

I use the "key" analogy when describing organization best practice: it's not about where you should *put* items, but where you can easily *find* them (like my house keys).

So when looking at "requirements" for each content type I'll suggest folders that optimize how that item is managed in terms of creation, updates, and selections.

- For re-use (like with Images), as Bart mentions, consolidate items into fewer folders.
- For tasks with lots of related parts, group these into containing folders.
- For speed in creation or selection, place items higher in the folder structure.
- To "flatten" heavily nested folders, use a naming convention (e.g. prefixes can let you remove one level of folders). Also, you might not need global or local folders because you might be able to tell by the context of the current publication.

Most setups I've seen or suggested at least lock down the first level or two for folders.

### Impact

You can cut & paste items so references to those items stay the same. However, here are some gotchas.

**First of all, be careful with renames and Content Porter since it's based on WebDAV paths. Rename them manually across environments, map the differences, or handle duplicates as needed.**

Folders are also related to:

- **Permissions** -- you can restrict read, write, delete, and localize permissions based on folders. Assuming a folder structure up front is okay, but might mean needing to set lots of folder permissions for groups later.
- **Visible drop-downs** -- it's not readily apparent, but `read` permissions on the folders that contain Schemas and Component Template changes what each user sees in the form views. This is easy to change later by cutting & pasting Schemas into subfolders as needed (refer to warning on Content Porter though).
- **Image Paths** -- Optionally image paths (if using template code to place images into Structure Groups) are based on folders. If needing to change the folder-based structure or paths later, then you'll have to unpublish and republish images. And since template can also indirectly publish images, this might mean republishing much of your website.
- **Training** -- Editors learn where everything is in a Tridion setup quickly and may not appreciate wide-scale changes without warning. Also, if you've developed custom training on how to make articles, the screenshots and paths will be out-of-date if you change the folders. :-)

*I talk more on the differences between organization in the [build versus management phases of a Tridion project in this post](http://www.createandbreak.net/2014/06/fields-and-folders-are-about-how-not.html).*

Answer (score 1):

As Pankaj already answered, there is no default structure, so this was choosen by your implementor and they should have provided with logic on what this folder structure is meant for.

Just looking at the names, I would expect you create global content in the Global folder,and local content in the Local folder and all Images in the Image folder.

But then on to the interesting part, there is indeed no recommended structure since it mostly is requirement driven. However there are concepts which make sense to always incorporate. Separating Templates and Schemas from user content by means of folders is definitely suggested. If not only because rights and permissions are set on folder level, so this gives you an easy way to control that. Using a certral images folder is also something you will often find back, since Tridion tries to promote reuse of your content, most important is that you can find the existing content back in a logical structure, hence a centralized images folder (which most of the times will contain a sub folder structure of course).

The impact of folder structure changes is hardly noticable. There could be an impact when you move sub folders to another folder, with regards to rights and permissions being derived from a parent organizational item. But for the rest when the template code refers to a certain folder by ID, the location of that folder doesn;t matter. Indeed when WebDAV URLs are used, then changing structure will have an impact, which is why certainly for folders, the usage of WebDAV URLs is not recommended.